# Зависимость модели от хелпера/сервиса

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

Web-приложение, MVC архитектура, из контроллера вызывается геттер-метод модели, результат выполнения которого должен быть обработан **методом класса-хелпера**? Инициализация класса-хелпера происходит окружающим фреймворком, с добавлением в DI-контейнер, получение экземпляра происходит вручную.

Вопрос: куда нужно вставлять вызов выделенного жирным? В контроллере или в моделе (оформив его как новое свойство)?

Т.е. вопросы:

- Насколько толстым может быть геттер в моделе? Является ли он в данном случае толстым?
- Является ли зависимость модели от `сервиса` (хоть и выполняющего роль хелпера) антипаттерном?

Comment: Что за метод-то?

Comment: формирование полного url картинки по имени файла

Comment: Логика формирования зависит от кучи конфигурационных параметров.

Comment: Уточнение: метод вызывается как в контроллере, так и в виде

Comment: Условный геттер может быть достаточно толстым, границы здесь довольно размыты, и запрещать создавать дополнительные геттеры с небольшой обработкой - неверная позиция. Другое дело, что если в этот момент в URL подставляется хост, то для меня такая операция была бы недопустимой, т.к. зона ответственности хранения изображения не должна знать конкретный хост, хотя и это утверждение справедливо толко внутри **моей** парадигмы программирования. Я бы в первую очередь отделил понятие модели от непосредственно хранимой сущности, и тогда все зависимости можно было бы хранить в репозитории, ->

Comment: а сам объект сущности оставить просто набором полей